# Opencv python error

Tags: python, opencv

I followed [this](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/#comment-72178) to install opencv. When I tested the C and Java samples, they worked fine. But the python samples resulted in a

```
 import cv2
 ImportError: No module named cv2
```

How can I fix this?

I am using python 2.7 and ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: have you tried the opencv example? Those that come with the library.

Comment: do you mean the samples?

Comment: yes those who come with the lib.

Comment: `python ~/opencv-2.4.9/samples/python2/turing.py`
is what I have tried and turing.py is in the sample python2 folder. When I do this, I get the above error

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For using OpenCv in Python, you gotta do one more step. Find the file called cv2.so or cv2.pyd (I'm not sure which one it is.)in the OpenCv installation directory.. copy paste it  to your site-packages folder inside Python installation directory.

Comment: Yes copy paste it .

Answer (score 0):

Install the library with apt, apt-get install python-opencv python-opencv-apps. It will resolve all the issues.